# Define behavior of an expectation function wrt derivative

Tags: probability-or-statistics, upvalues

I wanted to calculate the expressions for Ursell functions

$$u_n(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_1}\cdots \frac{\partial}{\partial a_n}\log E(\exp\sum a_i\sigma_i)\big|_{a_i=0}$$

The value, for example, for $n$=3 is:

$$u_3(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3)=E(\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3)-E(\sigma_1)E(\sigma_2\sigma_3)-E(\sigma_2)E(\sigma_3\sigma_1)-E(\sigma_3)E(\sigma_1\sigma_2)+2E(\sigma_1)E(\sigma_2)E(\sigma_3)$$

For doing that, I would like to define a derivative a function $E$ that conmutes with the derivative, in the sense that that $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_n}E(X)=E(\frac{\partial}{\partial a_n} X)$.

My attempt:

```
U[n_] := (Fold[D,
   Log[e[Exp[a /@ Range[n].(\[Sigma] /@ Range[n]) ]]],
   a /@ Range[n]
   ]
  )/. a[_] -> 0

e /: D[e[f], x] := e[D[f, x]]
e[x_Integer] := x
```

Could you tell my how to fix this? Another solution to the problem would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, using a custom derivative function

```
Format[X[i_]] = Subscript[\[Sigma], i];
Format[myE[i_]] = "E"[i];
d[f_, v_] := D[f, x] /. Superscript[fun_, sup_]'[x] -> Superscript[fun, sup  v][x];
U[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Block[{h}, 
                            h = Log[Superscript[TMP, 1][x]]; 
                            Do[h = d[h, X[i]];, {i, 1, n}]; 
                            h /. Superscript[TMP,1][x] -> 1 /.Superscript[TMP,y_][x] :> myE[y]
                         ]
```

Note that the `Format[]` function only changes how expressions are printed on screen, but not how they are accessed. Use `FullForm[]` to see how an expression actually looks like to *Mathematica* kernel.

Comment: You might want to add `Format[X[i_]] = Subscript[\[Sigma], i]
Format[myE[i_]] = "E"[i]`

Comment: Added your suggestion, looks much better now.